# How to get info from object in the datagrid while this object is Entity Framework object?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

I want to get the value of the selected cell as string. But I can't select it as an Entity Framework object.

I tried to do it with a list of objects not from Entity Framework and it works fine:

```
public MainWindow()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        using (SellEntities Context = new SellEntities())
        {
            var query = from t in Context.Categories
                        orderby t.Id
                        select new
                        {
                            t.Id,
                            CategoryName = t.Name
                        };
            CategoriesDataGridVeiw.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
        }
}

private void CategoriesDataGridVeiw_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
        var rows = CategoriesDataGridVeiw.SelectedItem as Category;

        if (rows != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(rows.Name);
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Null");

        CategoriesDataGridVeiw.UnselectAll();
}
```

Comment: This requires a [mcve]. It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is this variable (rows) always = null. I can't select Item from the datagrid as category or as any class made by Entity Framework . I'm trying to clear my question but I don't know how to describe it.

Comment: Well, it's obvious that `new
                        {
                            t.Id,
                            CategoryName = t.Name
                        }` can't be cast to `Category`. But I don't understand the problem description. *I can't select it as an Entity Framework object* -- Why not?

Comment: Thank you so much. you made me trace my code right finding out the solution. I've been 4 days stuck with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the datagrid contains query object, And I'm selecting the Items in the datagrid as category.
The solution is to make sure that the datagrid.ItemsSource equals to the thing that u want to cast to later.

```
CategoriesDataGridVeiw.ItemsSource = Context.Categories.ToList();
```

now I can use this:

```
CategoriesDataGridVeiw.SelectedItem as Category
```

thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/861716/gert-arnold . 
you made me think about it the right way.